# Remove "autoplay" attribute from <video> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following HTML:

```
<video width="552" height="572" id="video" autoplay preload="none" poster="image.png">
```

How would I go about removing `autoplay` entirely from the `<video>` element?

I've tried something like the following:

```
//Attempt
jQuery('video').remove('autoplay');

//Attempt
jQuery( 'video' ).removeClass( 'autoplay' );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**to Remove:**

plain javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].removeAttribute('autoplay');
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('VIDEO_ID').removeAttribute('autoplay');
```

With jQuery:

```
$('video').removeAttr("autoplay");
```

**To Add:**

plain javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].setAttribute('autoplay','');
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('VIDEO_ID').setAttribute('autoplay','');
```

With jQuery:

```
$('video').attr("autoplay","");
```

Answer (score 6):

`autoplay` Is an attribute, therefor use the `removeAttr` attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

`$(selector).removeAttr('autoplay');`

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method:

```
jQuery( 'video' ).removeAttr( 'autoplay' );
```

This will remove the `autoplay` attribute from each `video` element.

```
jQuery( '#video' ).removeAttr( 'autoplay' );
```

This will remove the `autoplay` attribute from the element with **ID** `video`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.removeAttr()` function.

```
jQuery('video').removeAttr('autoplay');
```

Haven't test it but should work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jquery('video').removeAttr('autoplay');
```